# How do you find roots using the quadratic formula?.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering how you could find the roots of a given equation using the quadratic formula.I'm already familiar with the quadratic formula, and somewhat familiar with roots, but this question that i found in my textbook ,is putting me even more off guard by the addition of α and β, what are they supposed to represent?.

Here is the actual question:

> Use the quadratic formula to find the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of this quadratic equation. Hence show in each case that $\alpha + \beta = \frac{-b}{a}$ and $\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$.

Equation = $-3x^2+10x-5=0$

Comment: Let $\alpha = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$; let $\beta = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.  Then find $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha\beta$.

Comment: It might help to mention that if the equation had been $x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0,$ or equivalently $(x-1)(x-2) = 0,$ then the roots would be $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 2$ (or they could be named in reverse order⁠—it won't matter, since both $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$ are the same when you use the reverse order), and in this case your task would be to show that $\alpha + \beta = -\frac{b}{c} = -\frac{-3}{1}$ and $\alpha \beta = \frac{c}{a} = \frac{2}{1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just as it says, the roots of the equation. So, for the given equation $$−3x^2+10x−5=0$$

We know that a quadratic equation has the form $ax^2+bx+c$, so in this equation, we have \begin{align}a&=-3\\
b&=10\\
c&=-5\end{align}

Now we can use the quadratic formula to find the roots

\begin{align}x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
&=\frac{-10\pm\sqrt{4\times(-3)\times(-5)}}{2\times -3}\\
&\color{white}{=}\vdots\\
\alpha&=\frac{5-\sqrt{10}}3\\
\beta&=\frac{5+\sqrt{10}}3
\end{align}

Now we can compute $\alpha+\beta$

\begin{align}\alpha+\beta&=\frac{5-\sqrt{10}}3+\frac{5+\sqrt{10}}3\\
&=\frac{5-\sqrt{10}+5+\sqrt{10}}3\\
&=\frac{10}3\\
&=-\frac{10}{-3}\\
&=-\frac ba\end{align}

Now finally we calculate $\alpha\beta$

\begin{align}\alpha\beta&=\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{10}}3\right)\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{10}}3\right)\\
&=\frac{(5+\sqrt{10})(5-\sqrt{10})}9\\
&=\frac{25+5\sqrt{10}-5\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{10}^2}9\\
&=\frac{25-10}9\\
&=\frac{15}9\\
&=\frac 53\\
&=\frac{-5}{-3}\\
&=\frac ca\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need the proof that why the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are written that way, so here is the proof:

suppose the equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$,

$\Rightarrow a(x^2+ 2\times \frac{b}{2a} + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}) + (c-\frac{b^2}{4a})=0$

$\Rightarrow (x+\frac{b}{2a})^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$

$\Rightarrow x+ \frac{b}{2a}= \pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$
$\Rightarrow x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

then $x_1+x_2= \frac{-2b}{2a} = \frac{-b}{a}$ and $x_1 \times x_2 = \frac{b^2-b^2+4ac}{4a^2}=\frac{4ac}{4a^2}=\frac{c}{a}$

So this is the **general proof** for your problem, you can also read more about this at Vietè theorem.